Inverter with open communication protocol
I want to set up a new solar installation in my home with gel batteries for normal domestic use.
I know little to nothing on the topic.
I would like an inverter that I can bring and/or make my own controller for. That is to say, there must be an accessible (physical) communications port, and it must be sufficiently documented to make the task of writing something for it reasonable.
What options am I looking at for such a device?
Does there already exist open (HTTP) API definitions out there that abstract the necessary concepts?
And also, what compatibility caveats do I need to keep in mind?

My own current goal would be to implement a telnet/ssh-like server and/or devfs-like structure to monitor and control it, but to also attach a HTTP API implementation could be interesting aswell (i.e. to make it easier for anyone to make their own app)

Welcome @lash This is an awesome question and sounds like a fun project. I'm tempted to take a crack at answering it. You seem to want to play with it and need to know what aspects of the inverter you can control before you decide what you want to control. Do you have any end goals in mind, like making a web interface or a phone app? Also, I don't think you posted it in the best place. It seems like a software and/or electronics question to me.

@ScottTramposch which stackexchange or other forum would you say is a better venue? I've updated the question re: goals

The Icon at the top of your screen on the far right lists 183 categories for you to choose from. There are several that would be a better match for you. There is DevOps, Electrical Engineering, Unix and Linux, Open Source, and many others. You might want to try Signal processing or Electrical Engineering. Whatever you decide, it's interesting to go through the list to see what they have. Meanwhile, I think you can leave this question here in case someone else has something to add to it. Not sure how that works.
